# CMake link shared library built from object libraries

Tags: c++, cmake

I can't get my cmake project running. It should build a library (Core) and then add this library to a new shared library. The problem is that the resulting library does not seem to link correctly against the executable.

```
fatal error: JNF_NEAT/body.h: No such file or directory
```

I have a CMake project which is structured as follows:

```
root
  -> CMakeLists.txt
  -> Core/
     -> CMakeLists.txt
     -> Sources/
  -> Examples/
     -> CMakeLists.txt
     -> Example1/
        -> CMakeLists.txt
        -> Sources/
```

root/CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.2)
project(JNF_NEAT)

set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/out/lib)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/out/examples)

add_subdirectory(Core)

add_library(JNF_NEAT SHARED $<TARGET_OBJECTS:Core>)
target_link_libraries(JNF_NEAT -lstdc++fs)

add_subdirectory(Examples)
```

root/Core/CMakeLists.txt

```
file(GLOB SOURCES Sources/*.cpp Sources/*.h)
add_library(Core OBJECT ${SOURCES})
```

root/Examples/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(XOR)
```

root/Examples/XOR/CMakeLists.txt

```
include_directories(../../out/lib)

file(GLOB SOURCES Sources/*.cpp Sources/*.h)
add_executable(XOR_EXAMPLE ${SOURCES})
target_link_libraries(XOR_EXAMPLE JNF_NEAT)
```

The entire source code is available [here](https://github.com/SirRade/JNF_NEAT/tree/d9d32d6dd9319b88520fca4337be3589bd7dba79).

#### Edit #1

I tried setting `target_include_directories(XOR_EXAMPLE BEFORE PUBLIC ../../out/lib)` before `target_link_libraries`

I also tried setting `include_directories(out/lib)` in the outer most CMakeLists.txt

#### Edit #2

On Linux [this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/787892013a0e66b423eb7cb7ed7e558e) error occures.

Comment: I would put all library include files, required for a user to use the library, in a separate directory named like the project "jnf_neat" , so these can be easily included  like "#include <jnf_neat/body.h>. (That helps installation under (maybe) "/user/local/include/inf_neat", too)

Comment: According to the linked project, path to the header file is `JNF_NEAT/Core/Sources/body.h`. You cannot include it via `#include <JNF_NEAT/body.h>`.

Answer (score 3):

The error

> JNF_NEAT/body.h: No such file or directory

is not a link error, but rather a compilation error.

Check that `JNF_NEAT/body.h` actually exists. If it does, it might not be included in the list of directories where the compiler looks for `#include`s. You can set this in CMake with the [`include_directories`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/include_directories.html) command.

> Add the given directories to those the compiler uses to search for include files. Relative paths are interpreted as relative to the current source directory.
>
> The include directories are added to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES directory property for the current CMakeLists file. They are also added to the INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES target property for each target in the current CMakeLists file. The target property values are the ones used by the generators.
>
> By default the directories specified are appended onto the current list of directories. This default behavior can be changed by setting CMAKE_INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES_BEFORE to ON. By using AFTER or BEFORE explicitly, you can select between appending and prepending, independent of the default.

Comment: Or target_include_directories: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html

Comment: @DieterLücking I added `target_include_directories(XOR_EXAMPLE BEFORE PUBLIC ../../out/lib)` before `target_link_libraries`, but it is still not working. I also tried setting the include_directories in the outer most CMakeLists and it didn't work.

Comment: @JST Which OS are you using? There's a check I'd like to suggest.

Comment: @DieterLücking macOS Sierra. I also have arch linux on my laptop. I will try running it on there.

Comment: @JST As a *temporary* check and workaround, can you look for the absolute path of the directory of this header, then follow the instructions [here](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/gccintro/gccintro_23.html) *before* running CMake?

Comment: @ami-tavory I set the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to my core source folder. The error still persists. (I also removed all the cached files)

Comment: Make sure that `JNF_NEAT` is a folder that has its parent folder in your include directories.